# define a CSS3 Attribute Selectors in less css

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I am trying to do a stuff related to **CSS3 Attribute Selectors with less css**...

What i am trying to do is, i have this following class which is in use in my code:-

```
*[class^="ui-icon-"] { 
    /*My Styles*/
}
```

That should be implemented in a manner that the styles of it will be implemented to another class that is defined after that, let say:-

```
/*Less*/
.another-class {
   *[class^="ui-icon-"];
}

/*Output CSS*/
.another-class {
   /*My Styles*/
}
```

Here, this is currently showing error on my webpage, does this have any solution?

Comment: What pseudo-class are you trying to define? All I see here is a class and an attribute.

Comment: mistake has been reviewed, sorry for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with trying to call an attribute selector like this.

- Mixins (reusable rules) in LESS should start with `.` or `#`, and
- they can not include characters like `"`, `=`, `*` and `^` (if they are unescaped).

So one solution is the one [laat suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785200/define-a-css3-attribute-selectors-in-less-css/16786943#16786943), where you add an extra selector to your rule, that you can call later as a mixin. Another way would be to define all your properties in `.another-class` (as this selector is a valid mixin name) and call this from inside the rule with the attribute selector, like this:

```
*[class^="ui-icon-"] {
    .another-class;
}

.another-class {
    /*My Styles*/
}
```

Or yet another way to add a set of properties to miltiple rules would be using a parametric mixin. Like this:

```
.mystyles(){/*My Styles*/}

*[class^="ui-icon-"] {
    .mystyles;
}

.another-class {
    .mystyles;
}
```

In both examples the rendered CSS will look like this:

```
*[class^="ui-icon-"] {
  /*My Styles*/
}
.another-class {
  /*My Styles*/
}
```

Comment: +1 for the good answer, you missed at least one other way though, so I added an answer of my own to make the answers to this question more complete.

Answer (score 3):

### One Other Way In LESS 1.4

[Martin's answer is very good.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785200/define-a-css3-attribute-selectors-in-less-css/16788055#16788055) Just for completeness, there is another way to do it in LESS 1.4 by *extending* the second selector. This could allow you to define the styles in your attribute selector first:

```
*[class^="ui-icon-"] { 
    /*My Styles*/
}

.another-class {
  &:extend(*[class^='ui-icon-'] all);
}
```

Which then groups them for final CSS output like so:

```
*[class^="ui-icon-"],
.another-class {
  /*My Styles*/
}
```

You can, of course, reverse how you define it:

```
.another-class  { 
    /*My Styles*/
}

*[class^="ui-icon-"] {
  &:extend(.another-class all);
}
```

Giving a similar grouped output:

```
.another-class,
*[class^="ui-icon-"] {
  /*My Styles*/
}
```

You can also add other styles needed:

```
*[class^="ui-icon-"] { 
    /*My Styles*/
}

.another-class {
  &:extend(*[class^='ui-icon-'] all);
  /* Other Styles for another-class */
}
```

Giving this output:

```
*[class^="ui-icon-"],
.another-class {
  /*My Styles*/
}
.another-class {
  /* Other Styles for another-class */
}
```

Comment: another +1 from me - for completing my answer with such an elegant solution once again ... I am a big fan of 1.4 ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it should actually be done, but this works for me.

```
._ui-icon, *[class^="ui-icon-"] { 
    color: black;
}

.another-class {
   ._ui-icon;
}
```